# Batch renaming with forfiles, or potentially Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-rename

I have an issue when trying to bulk rename files within folders using forfiles and Powershell. The issue I am having is I need to search for files with `_T_` in them, so I use the search notation `*_T_*.cr2` as they are all RAW files. In a given folder there will be 143 or so RAW files, 69 of them will have `_T_` in their names and the rest don't. What I want to achieve is run a quick command that weeds out all files with `_T_` in them and then adds an extra _ before the file.

So before: `Ab01_T_gh.cr2` and after `_Ab01_T_gh.cr2`
My issue is that searching for the `_T_` files causes the command to keep executing over and over and over, so the file eventually looks like `_____________Ab01etc` until it hits the Windows file name limit. 
Here's what my forfiles command looks like:

```
forfiles /S /M *_T_*.cr2 /C "cmd /c rename @file _@file"
```

It works but it works a little too well.

I also tried Powershell with the same result.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*_T_*.cr2" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { "_" + $_.Name}
```

Perhaps there's a way I could split up the "find" and "rename" parts of the code? Any help would be greatly appreciated! I can't manually separate out the `_T_` files as it would be very time intensive as each parent folder will sometimes have 75 subfolders with 143 RAW files in each.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*_T_.cr2) do (
set z=%%a
set z=!z:~,1!

if not !z!==_ rename %%a _%%a
)
```

I had to drop `forfiles` since I could not work with the `@` variables (maybe with `findstr`).
I resorted to a simple `for` loop on the pattern, and only rename if not already starts by underscore.

Recursive version:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /R . %%a in (*_T_.cr2) do (
echo %%~na%%~xa
set z=%%~na
set z=!z:~,1!

if not !z!==_ rename %%a _%%~na%%~xa
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works quite well! I had to tweak it @echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*_T_*.cr2) do ren "%%a" "_%%a"
 but once I did it renamed all the _T_ folders with an _ before them! There is only one challenge left, this batch file only works when placed in the subfolder and run from there. Ideally I'd like to run it from the parent folder and for it to automatically drill down into all the subfolders and work its magic. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've added an untweaked, but recursive version of my renamer. I did not get what your tweaks were exactly, but you should be able to do it again.

Comment: Thanks Jean-François, that did work! I had to add back in the * after "*_T_.cr2" but then it worked! However, a new problem has arisen, it doesn't work on files with an _ before them already. So, the one's that are named for example: _Spec_Right_T_20160805 afterwards should be called __Spec_Right_T_20160805 with a double underscore. The ones that were named LR04H_T_20160805 beforehand become _LR04H_T_20160805 which is perfect. Is there any way to tweak it so that it detects the ones that have _ before them already and adds a second one?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PowerShell version based on your original code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*_T_*.cr2" -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.Name.Substring(0,1) -ne '_' } |
Rename-Item -NewName $("_" + $_.Name)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help! Unfortunately it doesn't work, it returns the error Rename-Item: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. It also creates a file in the folder called _ with no extension which I suspect is one of the files renamed.